# Unable get response with R2DBC Postgresql WebFlux

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I am learning `R2DBC` with spring boot `WebFlux` and `Postgresql`. I have successfully configured with PostgreSQL database which is running on my local machine. I used the following dependencies and plugins.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compile group: 'io.r2dbc', name: 'r2dbc-postgresql', version: '1.0.0.M7'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

**Please find my code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class DemoServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class ResourceController {
    final ResourceRepository resourceRepository;

    @GetMapping("/method1") 
    public Flux<Resource> getResourcesMethod1(){
         return resourceRepository.deleteAll().thenMany(
                 Flux.just(new Resource("name1", "description1", new Date()), new Resource("name2", "description2", new Date()))
                 .flatMap(resourceRepository::save))
         .thenMany(
                 resourceRepository.findAll()
                 .flatMap(data -> {
                     return Flux.just(data);
                 }));
    }

    @GetMapping("/method2") 
    public Flux<Resource> getResourcesMethod2(){
        return resourceRepository.findAll();     
    }
}

@Configuration
class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
                PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .host("localhost")
                        .port(5432)
                        .username("postgres")
                        .password("password")
                        .database("mydatabase")
                        .build());
    }

}


interface ResourceRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Resource, Integer> {

}

@Data
class Resource {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    final String name;
    final String description;
    final Date createdDate;

    public Resource(String name, String description, Date createdDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
}
```

From the above code (using `getResourcesMethod1`) I was able to delete the data and insert data to the database table successfully.

However I could not retrieve any response from both those rest endpoints. I have used Postman to test and  it could not retrieve any thing... Just buffering...

What am I doing wrong here? I might missing a very basic thing. Any help would be grateful.

**EDIT**

If i print out flux in `getResourcesMethod2` it will print as `FluxOnErrorResume` instead of `FluxArray` which is expected though. I think this might with the database configuration. But i can not find the root course for this..

Answer (score 1):

Postman does not have support for returning streams.

there is a open feature request for it, but it's been there since 2018.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5040

you can use curl and disable the buffering with the `-N` flag to stream the response.

```
curl -N <your_url>
```

If you dont want to use curl, just for testing, then you can `collectList` and return a `Mono<List<T>>` to the client, and use postman.